# Need some clarification with Stacks and Templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, stack

So I have a problem I'm working on for my university class. Essentially the professor gives us a template in a header file and a main(), He asks us what would happen if we tried to "cout << s2.top();" and s2.pop(); after the multiple s2.push() and while loop (When the stack is empty). I already understand that after we cout the data in the stack, we pop() the last element until it is empty. Here is the code for stack.h:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
    vector<T> container;
public:
    Stack(): container() {}
    void push(T x) { container.push_back(x); }
    void pop() { if (container.size() > 0) container.pop_back(); }
    T top(){ if (container.size() > 0) return container.back(); }
    bool empty() { return container.empty(); }
};

#endif
```

Here is the main():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "stack.h"

main()
{
Stack<int> s1;

s1.push(4);
s1.push(3);
s1.push(2);
s1.push(1);
while (!s1.empty()) {
    cout << s1.top() << endl;
    s1.pop();
}

Stack<string> s2;
s2.push("Yoda said ");
s2.push("something ");
s2.push("to write ");
while (!s2.empty()) {
    cout << s2.top();
    s2.pop();
}

s2.pop();
cout << s2.top();

cout << endl;
```

}

I know we will get a segmentation fault or something similar since were trying to access or pop() an empty stack. He wants us to ONLY change stack.h. I've already added:

"void pop() { if (container.size() > 0) container.pop_back(); }"

And it will work for s2.pop().

My question is, when I try to add "if (container.size() > 0)" in the line:

"T top(){ return container.back(); }"

I still get a segmentation fault even though (at least I think) I'm checking the size before returning? How would i go about this one? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

If control reaches `}` of a function returning non-void, instead of reaching `return`, the behaviour is undefined. Anything could happen.

You have to add `else` to the `.top()`, and use it to return some kind of default value (you probably want `return {};`), or throw an exception, or prevent the function from returning in some other way.

Comment: Im not allowed to edit anything in the main fucntion :( I can only edit the template.

Comment: @Justin I said nothing about `main()`. I'm asking you to edit `.top()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
s2.pop();
cout << s2.top();
```

outside the loop is a) calling `pop()` on an empty container (just silly). b) calling `top()` on an empty container and using the result; *bug*.

Also `T top(){ if (container.size() > 0) return container.back(); }` results in undefined behaviour when container is empty since then the function does not return a `T` (which it *always* must).

Comment: I know that they are calling pop() and top() on an empty container. Thats the question he is asking us lol. We're supposed to change stack.h to avoid those errors. My question was why wont (if container.size() > 0) work for T top(){ return container.back(); }

Comment: @Justin see HolyBlackCat's answer and the UB bit I added to my own answer.